# How to get [author:year] as a citation and in the biography listing - this is almost to ISO style?

Tags: bibtex, citing

It is quite strange reading [ISO 690:2010(en)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:690:ed-3:v1:en) without purchasing the standard.

It seems at 2.3 they deviate from their own standard by using 2.3 [SOURCE: ISO/TR 9544:1988] as a citation.

(So much fo standards, but might sanity survive.)

How can I get [\author:\year] or (a\author:\year)?

Here is extract from the standard:

```
computer program
schedule or plan that specifies actions expressed in a form suitable for execution by a computer
[SOURCE: ISO/TR 9544:1988]
```

Just for reference, the citation list in the standard is [\arabicnumeral] and that makes no sense to me at all.

What does make sense to me is to always use the same style in the bibliography listing for reference purposes.  (a:y) or [a:y] How can this be achieved?

Comment: Note that the citation of ISO standards themselves is a bit tricky, since they (traditionally) don't follow the usual author-year scheme. It would be unusual to cite a work by Smith from 2010 as "Smith:2010" and some people don't like citing an ISO standard from 2010 as "ISO 2020". It is indeed odd that the standard itself does not use the citation style it defines properly itself, but frankly I would just ignore that. If I understand correctly ISO 690 technically prescribes no citation style at all, the only references to citation styles are in the informative annex, so go figure.

Comment: If you need to or want to (in the latter case there is still time to reconsider) use ISO 690, you can look into [`biblatex-iso690`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690), which implements the (apparently slightly stricter) Czech/Slovak interpretation of ISO 690.

Comment: @moewe Exactly what I need and it works with `\parencite{}` as well!  May I suggest you update your MWE on the website with `\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}` and post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to take the way other ISO standards are references in the standard itself as an indication of what a citation should look like in ISO style.

Indeed if I understand correctly, the prescriptive part of ISO 690 does not describe any particular citation style. Citation styles are only defined in the informative Annex A. That annex describes numeric citations or author-year citations.

If you want ISO 690, you should look into [`biblatex-iso690`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690), that bundle of styles implements the Czech/Slovak translation of ISO 690 (ČSN ISO 690), which is stricter in some areas (I have been told; I expect it is  still fully compatible with the English translation).

For ISO 690 author-year citations you would use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: SIGFRIDSSON, Emma; RYDE, Ulf, 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry. Vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395. Available from doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Note that technically speaking, the standard is far more flexible in some areas than some people seem to think. The punctuation scheme in the reference list for example is not part of ISO 690, it just requires a consistent scheme. In particular the punctuation scheme in the examples is not prescriptive.

Yet there are some things that ISO 690 requires that I find a bit ... odd to say the least (medium designator, insistence on ALL CAPS in ČSN ISO 690, language switching, publisher for `@article`s, ...), so unless you are somehow forced to use ISO 690, I would recommend you find a different style.

Comment: To prevent (ISO 2020) I use `author = {ISO 80000-1:}` and the result is (ISO 80000-1: 2009) which makes much more sense to me.

Comment: @skvery As I say, citing standards is tricky in author-year styles, because they don't really fit the author-year scheme and people have a very particular expectation for the citation output that may not be strictly compatible with an author-year style. I would probably use `shorthand = {ISO 80000-1: 2009},` or some such because I don't like to abuse fields in that way, but if you are happy with the result, who am I to say you shouldn't do that?